# Could Crew Dragon Make an Emergency Landing on Land?

Tags: landing, capsule

Could a capsule designed for ocean splashdown still land successfully on land in an emergency? The speed of the capsule is slowed to ~15 MPH, which seemingly wouldn't destroy the capsule.

Comment: It may damage the capsule but the astronauts should not be injured. It is not a matter of speed but of decceleration. Landing on rocks or concrete may be harder than on soft sand.

Comment: Depending on the speed of impact, there isn't much difference between hitting water and hitting concrete anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe all capsules are rated for an emergency land landing, in case there is an issue near launch. If the winds were particularly unfavorable, it could result in a landing between the pad and the ocean, which would be bad. I know for a fact that Apollo was rated to allow such landings, and I believe Crew Dragon is as well.

Note that it is for something really unforeseen where this might happen. I don't think they would attempt a land landing unless absolutely essential.

Answer (score 0):

See, for example,  [Teslarati](https://www.teslarati.com/spacex-crew-dragon-emergency-landing/) article w/ recent Musk conversations.  The retros could certainly combine with the 'chutes to bring the capsule to a safe earth landing.